# Horst Herrlich, Topology I, Exercise 4.4.22 (2), page 123

Tags: general-topology

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I'm simply stuck and have no idea how to solve it.

**Given:**

$(\underline{X_i})_{i\in I}, J \subset I$, where J is infinite and each $\underline X_i$ is non-empty.

$\forall j \in J: A_j \subsetneq X_j$

**Prove:**

$int_{\prod \underline X_i} (\bigcap\{ p_j^{-1}[A_j] \ | \ j \in J\}) = \emptyset$

Comment: Recall and use the definition of the product topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$. For $i\in I\setminus J$ let $A_i=X_i$. Then

$$A=\bigcap_{j\in J}p_j^{-1}[A_j]=\prod_{i\in I}A_i\,.$$

If $A$ has non-empty interior, there are a finite $F\subseteq I$ and non-empty open sets $U_i$ for $i\in F$, such that if we set $U_i=X_i$ for $i\in I\setminus F$ and let $U=\prod_{i\in I}U_i$, then $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $A$. That is,

$$\varnothing\ne\prod_{i\in I}U_i\subseteq\prod_{i\in I}A_i\,,$$

so $U_i\subseteq A_i$ for each $i\in I$. This, however, is impossible: $J$ is infinite, so there is a $j\in J\setminus F$, and $U_j=X_j\supsetneqq A_j$.